# Array allocation for CPU and GPU functions in NUMBA

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to write some functions in numba that I can interchangeably use for different targets (cpu, cuda, parallel). The probelm I'm having is the allocation of a new array is different for cuda device code, e.g.:

```
cuda.local.array(shape, dtype)
```

vs. doing something similar for a CPU function, i.e.

```
np.empty(shape, dtype)
```

Is there a clever way how to deal with this without having to write separate functions?

Comment: couldn't you test for type in your function?

Comment: the problem is i cannot have any statement in my functions that doesn't work, since numba compiles the code and freaks out. Otherwise i would do a simple if/else or such.
The natural way to handle that would be preprocessor directives in C for that, but there is no such thing available for python

Comment: Something along the lines of `patch` method of [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to redefine `cuda.local.array` as `np.zeros` via an `if` statement might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one dirty workaround for the problem. It is the only way that I could make it work.
Use the `@myjit` decorator instead of `@jit` and `@cuda.jit` and allocate all arrays as `cuda.local.array`.

```
def myjit(f):
'''
f : function
Decorator to assign the right jit for different targets
In case of non-cuda targets, all instances of `cuda.local.array`
are replaced by `np.empty`. This is a dirty fix, hopefully in the
near future numba will support numpy array allocation and this will
not be necessary anymore
'''
if target == 'cuda':
    return cuda.jit(f, device=True)
else:
    source = inspect.getsource(f).splitlines()
    assert '@myjit' in source[0]
    source = '\n'.join(source[1:]) + '\n'
    source = source.replace('cuda.local.array', 'np.empty')
    exec(source)
    fun = eval(f.__name__)
    newfun = jit(fun, nopython=True)
    # needs to be exported to globals
    globals()[f.__name__] = newfun
    return newfun
```

Comment: 4 years later, any alternatives?

Comment: Darn.. thanks for the quick reply! Also, even if a bit hacky, nice solution wrapped in a function! I had thought about doing something like this for a different reason but didn't want to get in over my head. I'll keep this in mind